glmmTMB ZINB model non-convergence
I am looking for help with fitting a ZINB model with mixed-effects. The model which I intend to fit contains a random-intercept (three variables/terms denoting the nested, hierarchical group structure) and a random-slope (time variable with 165 time points). The issue is that the model produces an output for random-intercept model, but fails to produce an output (produces an error) for random-slope model.
I started a discussion with package author here:
https://github.com/glmmTMB/glmmTMB/issues/1023
My model formula looks like this:
var9 ~ var13 + var14 + var19 + var20 + var34 + var46 + var47 + var50 + var51 + var52 + var56 + var57 + var59 + var60 + var62 + var65 + var66 + var89 + var90 + var91 + var92 + var93 + var94 + (var2 | var4/var3/var1)

He suggested specifying time variable as continuous in random-slope formula and refitting the model. It returned an output on a test dataset which is roughly 1% of the original dataset (had NA values for AIC, BIC, loglik, deviance), but failed on the full dataset.
In (function (start, objective, gradient = NULL, hessian = NULL,  :
  NA/NaN function evaluation
Error in ff(x, order = 1) : 
  inner newton optimization failed during gradient calculation
outer mgc:  NaN 
Error in (function (start, objective, gradient = NULL, hessian = NULL,  : 
  NA/NaN gradient evaluation
Calls: glmmTMB ... with.default -> eval -> eval -> do.call -> <Anonymous>
Timing stopped at: 5258 879.3 6540
Execution halted

Attributes of my dataset:
My original dataset has 2,429,283 observations.
var4 has 53 levels.
interaction(var4, var3) has 375 levels.
interaction(var4, var3, var1) has 61125 Levels.
I am currently looking at some references suggested here:
glmmTMB - Model convergence problem; non-positive-definite Hessian matrix
Could anyone kindly advice on how to get the model to converge and obtain a valid output. I am happy to share the test dataset and any other details as needed. Thank you in advance for your help.

I formatted your question to make it more readable. Please check that I did not spoil anything.

I think to get a full answer you would probably need to hire someone, although maybe you can find someone willing to devote enough time to this. But I would guess that the 3 level interaction just has way too many levels. Even if the model converged, how would you interpret this?  And, from your number of levels, it looks like some cells are empty, which can cause problems.

Cross-posting is deprecated: https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5115/what-to-do-if-we-see-cross-posting . I'm going to try to help a little bit on Stack Overflow. However, I think you will probably end up having to simplify your model, or hire a statistical/data-analytic consultant, or both.

Thank you for informing me, @BenBolker! I shall refrain from cross-posting in the future.

The question is reformatted perfectly. Thank you, @PeterFlom!

@PeterFlom, my main research interest is only in the model fixed-effects. I am choosing to include random effects to account for time-based correlations. From reading online about mixed-effects modelling, I understand that including random-effects also improve fixed-effects estimates. Could you clarify what you meant by "And, from your number of levels, it looks like some cells are empty, which can cause problems."? How did you pinpoint the issue?

The number of interactions isn't a multiple of the number of levels of the main variables.
